# Aggregation function does not work on AgensGraph

Tags: aggregate-functions, agens-graph

The message pop up like "Function min(jsonb) is not unique".

Aggregation function like `count()` in return clause does not work.

When I try implicit type cast, functions are detected in multiple.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please at least specify the command that you entered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please include the query that throws the error.
Meanwhile I hope this helps...

```
create ({name: 'John', age: 25})
create ({name: 'Rose', age: 22})
create ({name: 'Mary'})
create ({name: 'Jane', age: 33});

match(n) return max(n.age::"numeric");
match(n) return min(n.age::"numeric"), avg(n.age::"numeric"), stDev(n.age::"numeric");
match(n) return sum(n.age::"numeric"), collect(n.age) as "list of ages", count(n.age);
```

Thanks, Joe